# Does ActiveRecord association creation always pull objects from the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have some code like this:

```
u = ... some user ...
u.clubs << Club.new(:name => "Stu's house of Disco")
```

With a join model, ClubMemberships that is created automatically via the above.

So far, so good.  However, users have an attribute that is kept *in memory*, not in the database, for security reasons, and when the "<<" method fires, it **reloads** the user from the database, and thus blows up some code in ClubMemberships#after_create that depends on the user having its secret decoder ring intact, which it does not have when freshly loaded from the database.  This seems a bit strange: why is it loading the user when we have a perfectly good one sitting right there?  More importantly, is there a way to work around this, or are we going to have to simply create our own add_club method for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what we did.  It's an ugly hack, and superior solutions would be welcome.

We created a @@secret_decoder_ring class variable in User with a hash linking the object's ID and the secret, non-DB piece of information, so that if the object in question has been seen and had the secret data filled in, it will be visible in the future.

In reality, we only want the visibility to be the duration of a request processed in Rails, so we have an after_filter that wipes the data in question.

Ugly? Yes, but it does the job for the time being.